# How do you use devServer.proxy in Vue?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios, proxy

I'm currently trying to proxy my requests from my Vue app so I can send cookies back from the server that exists separate from my frontend.

I have my frontend on port 8080 and server on port 3000. However, when I try to configure my proxy to use port 3000 in Vue using devServer.proxy, it sends the request to 8080 still.

Here is my code in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:3000',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my axios request:

```
axios.post(`/api/auth/login/`, loginDetails, {
        withCredentials: true, 
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('login response: ', response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    });
```

Here is the error I get that shows the frontend is still sending to 8080:
[image: Client side console error]

I also tried using the following in vue.config.js and not having anything prefixed to the request url, but to no avail.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

Here is the documentation that I am using https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver

Comment: "it sends the request to 8080 still" - it's supposed to, that's how a proxy works. It's unknown why there's 404 in your case.

Comment: I see, ya it's got me quite confused at the moment. The request is successful if I manually change the axios req to url https://localhost:3000/auth/login. But when I try using the proxy it produces 404.

Comment: You can check both proxy and server logs. You didn't show the response, it could give some idea at which point it went wrong. It's a regex and should be '^/api' instead of '/api', otherwise it's done as you did and expected to work

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out after looking at the server logs. It didn't occur to me to check there since I assumed 404 meant it couldn't even find the server.

The issue was it proxied with /api/auth/login but my server route only had /auth/login so it sent 404. I'm not sure if this is correct but I just prepended my server routes with /api and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

After taking a look at the server logs, I found out that the proxy was working and it was trying to find the /api/auth/login route on my server. However, I only had /auth/login so the server sent the 404 status.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but I simply prepended the server route with /api and it worked like so:

```
app.use('/api/auth', authRouter)
```

Previously it looked like this:

```
app.use('/auth', authRouter)
```

Thank you to Estus Flask for the tips in the comments.